# What is this compound-leaf tree in Southern India?

Tags: botany, species-identification

I am staying in *South India*. I didn't find any flowers to this tree; just leaves.

Just seeing the leaf, I am guessing Arabian Jasmine, but my tree doesn't have flowers or seed buds like Arabian Jasmine has.

[image: tree]

Comment: I added more clarity image, is it ok to ID this plant ?

Comment: A clear shot of the whole leaf would be nice. Also a comment about where it's growing and how big it is would be helpful. Thanks.